# Living in France & working remotely in Germany - Tax class

Tags: taxes, germany

I am working remotely from France for a German university.

The HR department is claiming they need to put me in class VI.
They say that since I am a remote worker (I have a normal public sector contract), they need to put me in class VI.

From what I've gather tax class VI is either attributed when the tax id is amiss, or when two jobs are held (then for the second, less earning job).

However the paper work for the tax id was done and i signed a paper testifyng that the univ will be my only employer & source of income.

Any thoughts? Any one can help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you a tax residence of France/Germany/both?

Comment: Did you fill out some forms "für beschränkt einkommensteuerpflichtige Arbeitnehmer"?